# Symfony: две формы одного типа на одной странице

Tags: symfony5

Пытаюсь вывести две формы в одном контроллере. На выходе получается что они имеют одинаковое имя. Следовательно обработчик не понимает какую отправили на проверку.
Визуально выглядит как

```
// Форма
class ExampleFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    // тут поля
    }
}

// В контроллере
$form1 = $this->createForm(BankFormType::class, []);
$form2 = $this->createForm(BankFormType::class, []);

// здесь ошибка, имена совпадают
$form1->handleRequest($request);
$form2->handleRequest($request);

if ($form1->isSubmitted() && $form1->isValid()) { }
```

Конечно я могу сделать две разные формы, но хотелось бы решить эту задачу. Так как пока в ней пара полей

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ. Воспользоваться фабрикой форм в цикле. Также обработчик *isSubmitted()* нужно пропустить через цикл

```
$forms[] = $this->container
    ->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder('form_example_' . $i, new ExampleType, $data)
    ->getForm()
    ->createView();

foreach ($forms as $form) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    // Проверка
    }
}
```